# Can "earnings" be used in place of "income"?

Tags: meaning, paraphrasing

As far as I'm concerned,

> **income**: money you get from all sources.

> **earnings**: money you get from your job.

To me, there's a slight difference between them. However, I have seen them used interchangeably in writing samples to talk about people's incomes. Is it incorrect? Do IELTS examiners mind this and consider it improper paraphrasing?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it can't be answered by us.  We are not IELTS examiners.  So we can't say what the requirements for a particular examination are.  The context matters.  If you are talking to an economist (or a taxman) then certainly it is important to make the distinction between income and earnings. But most people don't have much income apart from their earnings so for most people it doesn't make a difference. Note that this is English Language Learners, and not IELTS test-takers stack exchange.

Comment: I am not an IELTS examiner either, but I do know that money acquired from share dividends is often called 'earnings'.

Comment: "Investment income refers to any interest or dividend paid to or from domestic investors. It includes earnings from investments such as stocks, bonds, and loans"

Comment: _UK residents' retained earnings from investments abroad fell_ [between April and June 2023] (UK Office for national Statistics)

Comment: "Earnings" will often be used as a synonym for wages/salary for a job, in contrast to "unearned income", although it can be used differently or more widely. But there are many other sources of money beyond wages: rents/unearned income; social security; pensions; gambling winnings; money from selling property, shares/stocks, and goods (capital gains); inheritances; refunds/reimbursements; etc. They may or may not be important depending on what is being discussed. I have to ask though: if you have doubts over earnings, why not use income?

Comment: @JamesK Actually, there are people on the site telling me they were IELTS trainers, so it's not pointless in asking the question. I asked 2 questions here, one being related to what IELTS examiners think and the other is if it's correct to use the phrases interchangeably in writing.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey so you mean the meaning of "earnings" goes beyond my definition and it can be used in place of "income"?

Comment: @StuartF because it's a whole essay talking about people's incomes. I almost had to use the word in all of my sentences, so I think it's good to have an alternative. This can show the examiner that my vocabulary is not limited.